# What happens if a free radical is placed in absolute vacuum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, vacuum

I'd like to know  what happens if a free radical has no material around to interact with.

I have asked many people but I am not satisfied with their answer. I know there is nothing like absolute vacuum, it's just a hypothetical condition I am thinking of.

Can give some theory or insight?

Comment: Free radicals have limited reactivity and you wouldn't need vacuum to stop them from reacting.

Comment: @Mithoron no i am not asking, how to make them stop reacting, i am just wondering what will happen if they dont get anything to react with? Will it collapse or something crazy will happen.

Comment: Why would you think something would happen? If there's nothing to react with, it won't react.

Comment: Free radicals are generally stable, but very reactive. There would have to be excess of energy in one of them to fragmentate like in mass spectroscopy.

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question? Att: @Manishearth

Answer (score 2):

Hmmn, an interesting question. The most logical answer is that nothing would happen, since there is nothing to react with. But in science, it all boils down to empirical evidence. Which can only be acquired with experiments.

Comment: u stated that nothing will happen and for how much time, i do have limited knowledge but there are attractive forces in an atom for eg lets take eg of Cl, if there is radical of Cl then it will have lesser electrons than it is supposed to have to be stable, and would more number of protons pull it in, i mean electrons will be pulled towards nucleus.

Comment: Hmmn, possibly.